# Regularity of Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ an open and bounded open set, $f$ is a bounded function, $|f|<M_1$, $M_1$ is a constant. Is it true that the unique weak solution $u$ of the Laplace equation
$$-\triangle u = f$$
is in $C^{1,r}$, where $r\in (0,1)$ and $$||u||_{C^{1,r}} \leq M_2,$$ where $M_2$ is another constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to obtain a *unique* weak solution, you additionally need some boundary condition. Let us for sake of exposition assume that we require $u \in W_0^{1, 2}(\Omega)$. Then your statement is true in the sense that for any $r \in (0, 1)$ and $M_1 \gt 0$, there is $M_2 \gt 0$ such that if $f \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ with $\|f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \le M_1$ then the corresponding solution fulfills $\|u\|_{C^{1+r}(\overline \Omega)} \le M_2$.

One way to prove that: For any $p \in (1, \infty)$, the operator $A: W_0^{2, p}(\Omega) \to L^p(\Omega)$, $\varphi \mapsto \Delta \varphi$ is an ismorphism. Thus, if $u$ is a solution to your PDE with right hand side $f$, then $u = A^{-1} f$ and hence $\|u\|_{W^{2, p}(\Omega)} \le \|A^{-1}\| \|f\|_{L^p(\Omega)} \le C \|f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$.

By [Morrey's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Morrey%27s_inequality), $W^{2, p}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow C^{1 + r}(\overline \Omega) $ for $r = 1-\frac np$ provided $p > n$, so that we obtain the desired inequality by choosing $p$ large enough.

A more elementary proof can be found in Gilbarg–Trudinger, if I remember correctly.

Finally, a small warning: The argument fails for $p=\infty$ and you do *not* obtain a bound in $C^2(\overline \Omega)$.